# Getting Started with VMWare-Clarity Design System

Tags: vmware-clarity

I would like advice on how best to move my company toward using VMWare's Clarity system, or something very much like it. Should we use it as a template? Fork it? Integrate parts of it over time?

By Q4 of 2018 we would like to:

- have a decent Design System
- develop in Angular 2
- use Bootstrap 4

Currently we are here:

- No Design System
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- AngularJS

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: too broad Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Clarity Design System is composed of several parts.

There are Design resources - sketch templates for the light and dark themed components as well as documentation and guidelines for using them. In addition, we publish three packages

1. **@clr/icons** - an icons library that can be used standalone. The icons are web-components and can be used like any other element in a project after you integrate it into the app
2. **@clr/ui** - standalone html/css for clarity themed components. For obvious reasons more advanced components like the datagrid or wizard are not part of this
3. **@clr/angular** - Clarity components for Angular applications.

To answer a few of your questions.

**Q. Should we use it as a template?** 
A. No, Clarity (@clr/angular) should be integrated into your Angular application so you can use the components to build up the application with them.

**Q. Fork it?** 
A. you are welcome to fork the code, its open source software (MIT License). If you want to stay up to date with the latest bug fixes and enhancements though I would suggest integrating it into a project and keeping up with the incremental releases. We generally try to release once a week and callout breaking changes at least two versions with deprecations.

**Q. Integrate parts of it over time?**
A. I (as a Clarity UI Engineer) would recommend adopting it fully from the beginning when you start your next Angular app. If not, you run the risk of competing design systems and conflicting styles and UX patterns.

We do not recommend using Clarity with Bootstrap 4. Even though our grid is based on an earlier beta version of Bootstrap 4. We would like to remove that as a dependency in the future.

Comment: Thanks very much for the guidance, @hippeelee! This gives me a _much_ clearer idea of our options for the near and less-near future.

Comment: You are welcome @ChristianBriggs - if this meets your needs could you accept it as the answer? Thanks.